How do I avoid banding in volumes that appear only on every other frame?
I am rendering out a sequence and have noticed that there is a circular banding happening within a volume, but only on every other frame. This happens both on render output and in rendered view within the viewport, but again, only on every other frame.
To note: The camera is inside the volume, rendering in cycles, GPU Compute, 128 samples, denoise on for render (not viewport)
I have tried the following, with no success.
-Increasing and decreasing the step amount and max step amount in the volume tab
-Adjusting scale of the noise texture controlling the volume
-Adjusting X and Y scales of the noise texture in the mapping node
-Adjusting the handles on the color ramp also controlling the volume
-Adjusting the HDRI Z rotation (I thought the banding was a result of light emitted from said HDRI)
I have included links to the first 5 frames of the sequence (ignore content, client project). The banding happens on every even frame (2, 4). If I need to upload any other images or screenshots, please let me know.
Frame 001: https://ibb.co/px7WYRv
Frame 002: https://ibb.co/QkDpY3S
Frame 003: https://ibb.co/ZGS9CFt
Frame 004: https://ibb.co/jRqjxSF
Frame 005: https://ibb.co/kS7ZHKX
Thank you in advance for your help, hoping to get this solved asap.
